# How to write dataframe to file so that regardless of length of column values, the values are adjacent without spaces

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, fixed-width

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3
1 06  1
06 1  1
0 08  1
08 0  1
0 06  1
06 0  1
```

I want to write to text file in fixed-width format so that it looks like this:

```
1061
0611
0081
0801
0061
0601
```

At the moment, I'm using write.fwf from gdata:

```
write.fwf(colnames=FALSE, x=df,file='file.txt', sep="")
```

But that produces output like this:

```
1 061
061 1
0 081
080 1
0 061
060 1
```

.. the spaces are preserved.

I'm thinking I convert each row to a single value with rowwise() mutate(), then output, or convert to single rows using read.table -- though that seems to eat the leading zeros, which I need

But I wanted to see what the most intuitive way to accomplish this task is.

Comment: `do.call(paste0, DF)`

Comment: @Roland could you elaborate? Error in -do.call(paste0, df) : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: You seem to have a `-` in front of the do.call, which is the unary operator. Btw, re "the spaces are preserved"  -- you provided no reproducible data containing spaces ... I guess what I edited in must be incorrect; maybe you can correct it. (I'll revert my edit.)

Comment: That's right. Your solution is great! If you or @roland want to post, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a vector in R, as suggested in comments, or use:

```
write.table(df, "file.txt", sep = "", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```